# PayPal smart buttons guest dropdown checkout in a react project

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment, payment-processing

I'm using payapl smart buttons in the main react app at my work.

Now everything working fine except that i need to display the guest checkout drop down, and instead there's a small window that pops up by paypal.

How can i fixed this issue so the paypal dropdown inputs will display ?

I tried ask chatGPT also search in the paypal docs but i didnt find anything
The code:

```
<PayPalScriptProvider
            options={{
                clientId: PayPalClientID,
                vault: true,
                intent: "subscription",
                components: "buttons",
            }}
        >
            <PayPalButtons
                createSubscription={(data, actions) => {
                    operations...
                    return actions.subscription.create({
                        plan_id: planId,
                        start_time: startDateTime,
                    });
                }}
                onApprove={async (data, actions) => {
                    operations...
                }}
                onError={(err) => console.error(err)}
                onCancel={(res) => console.warn(res)}
            ></PayPalButtons>
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
```